# How many X lettered words can I make

Tags: combinations

[image]

I've had problems with a similar question before. Is this literally 7?

Comment: seems like it is literally 7

Answer (score 1):

The $7$ letters of the word **dynamic** are all different, so all the possible 1-letter words are:

"d"

"y"

"n"

"a"

"m"

"i"

"c"

Which are literally 7.